# Camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback) doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have a problem with the android autoFocus() function.
I just want my App to auto focus when taking a picture.

```
camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
```

doesn't work at all.
Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, params.getFocusMode()); prints ' auto '.
My Camera does support autofocus^^

Comment: could you include more code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the camera preview?  The [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus%28android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback%29) says:

> This method is only valid when preview is active (between startPreview() and before stopPreview()).